# How to modify a column if it happens to be a MySQL type?

Tags: mysql, alter-table

I have a table called `sidebar_items` and it has a `Type` column, which is of type `enum('image', 'html')`. I would like to change this column to be of type `enum('image', 'html', 'structure')`. I have tried this:

```
alter table sidebar_items modify Type Type enum('image', 'html', 'structure');
```

It gives me the error of

```
alter table sidebar_items modify Type Type enum('image', 'html', 'structure')   Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Type enum('image', 'html', 'structure')' at line 1
```

I have tried with `Type` as well. Can I make this query work?

Alternatively, I can resolve the problem by:

- creating a `temp` table with the same structure as `sidebar_items`
- migrating the records from `sidebar_items` to the `temp` table
- dropping `sidebar_items`
- recreating `sidebar_items` with the new type for `Type`
- migrating the records from the `temp` table to `sidebar_items`
- dropping the `temp` table

However, I am interested to know whether there are any simpler solutions, possibly with a single `alter table` command.

Comment: What did I miss to deserve a downvote?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct syntax is:

```
ALTER TABLE sidebar_items MODIFY `Type` ENUM('image', 'html', 'structure');
```

with the [`ALTER TABLE ... MODIFY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html) command, you do not need to specify the column name twice, but you'd need it for `ALTER TABLE ... CHANGE`.

> You can rename a column using a CHANGE old_col_name new_col_name
>   column_definition clause. To do so, specify the old and new column
>   names and the definition that the column currently has. For example,
>   to rename an INTEGER column from a to b, you can do this:
>
> `ALTER TABLE t1 CHANGE a b INTEGER;`
>
> To change a column's type but not the name, CHANGE syntax still
>   requires an old and new column name, even if they are the same. For
>   example:
>
> `ALTER TABLE t1 CHANGE b b BIGINT NOT NULL;`
>
> You can also use MODIFY to change a column's type without renaming it:
>
> `ALTER TABLE t1 MODIFY b BIGINT NOT NULL;`
>
> MODIFY is an extension to ALTER TABLE for Oracle compatibility.

Comment: Oh, I missed that. Thanks. Will accept your answer.